# Deploy HSTS including subdomains if main domain is www (no preloading yet)

Tags: no-www, multi-subdomains, hsts

I want to deploy HSTS for `*.example.com` but we don't have web content on `example.com`. Instead, `www.example.com` is our main site and we have hundreds of (partly unknown) subdomains, so we don't want to use HSTS preload right away (just in case)...

What is the best way to deploy HSTS anyways?

My plan was to include an image (1x1 transparent png) on our most used websites which is served from `https://example.com/hsts/` and sets the approprieate header.

This way we should be able to reach a huge audience and are also able to disable it again, before actually deploying HSTS preload.

Are there better ways? I can't really come up with an alternative.